# Azure + Cassandra certified by Bitnami VM + nodejs app: Cannot connect to cassandra from remote app

Tags: node.js, azure, cassandra, azure-virtual-machine, datastax-node-driver

Using datastax nodejs driver: `'cassandra-driver'`

Connecting to database in my nodejs app server backend as:

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: [ '${azure_vm_ip}' ] });
```

Output log:

```
{ [Error: All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, azure_vm_ip:9042: Error: Connection timeout. See innerErrors.]
  innerErrors:
   { 'azure_vm_ip:9042':
      { [Error: Connection timeout]
        message: 'Connection timeout',
        info: 'Cassandra Driver Error' } },
  info: 'Represents an error when a query cannot be performed because no host is available or could be reached by the driver.',
  message: 'All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, azure_vm_ip:9042: Error: Connection timeout. See innerErrors.' }
```

Questions:

- Should I edit something on the default `cassandra.yaml` file? If
  so, what?
- Should I do something with firewall? If so, what?
- Should I pass in more options in `new cassandra.Client({
  contactPoints: [ '${azure_vm_ip}' ] })`? If so, What?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set rule for 9042 port in NSG. Also check whether the same port is in listening mode inside the VM.